# 2 identical items in a list with the same id get id value modified in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this view in which I need to display twice the same item. So I pass a list of my model and this list contains twice the same item.

Here's how I display them:

```
<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Confirm", "Inventory"))
    {

        <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Item Name</th>
               (...)
        </tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].OtrObj.ObjName)</td>
                    (...)

                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].OtrObjID)
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <div class="float-right">
            <input type="submit" value="Ready!"/>    
        </div>
    }
</p>
```

I'm sure that it occurs in the view because just when I send the view each items in my list carries the right "ObjID".

But when the page is rendered, the result is like this:

item 1:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field OtrObjID must be a number." 
    data-val-required="The OtrObjID field is required." 
    name="[0].OtrObjID" type="hidden" value="1" />
```

item 2:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field OtrObjID must be a number." 
    data-val-required="The OtrObjID field is required." 
    name="[1].OtrObjID" type="hidden" value="2" />
```

Why? I really don't get it. Can anyone help me out on this?

Here is the HTML output for those items:

```
<p>
    <form action="/Inventory/Confirm" method="post">         
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                ...
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Item one</td>

                    <td><input checked="checked" class="state1" name="[0].Destination" style="width: 50px" type="radio" value="State 1" /></td>
                    <td><input class="state2" name="[0].Destination" style="width: 50px" type="radio" value="State 2" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="field1" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field m_Field1 must be a number." data-val-required="The m_Field1 field is required." name="[0].m_Field1" style="width:200px" type="text" value="0,99" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="[0].m_Field1" data-valmsg-replace="false">Field 1 must be a number.</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="field2" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field m_Field2 must be a number." data-val-required="The m_Field2 field is required." name="[0].m_Field2" style="width:200px" type="text" value="1,00" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="[0].m_Field2" data-valmsg-replace="false">Field 2  must be a number.</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="field3" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field m_Field3 must be a number." data-val-required="The m_Field3 field is required." name="[0].m_Field3" style="width:200px" type="text" value="1,00" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="[0].m_Field3" data-valmsg-replace="false">Field 3 must be a number.</span>
                    </td>
                    <td><a href="/Inventory/DisplayItem/2">See other information</a></td>

                    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field OtrObjID must be a number." data-val-required="The OtrObjID field is required." name="[0].OtrObjID" type="hidden" value="1" />
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ObjID must be a number." data-val-required="The ObjID field is required." name="[0].ObjID" type="hidden" value="1" />
                    <input name="[0].m_Field1" type="hidden" value="0,99" />
                    <input name="[0].m_Field2" type="hidden" value="1,00" />
                    <input name="[0].m_Field3" type="hidden" value="1,00" />
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Item 2</td>

                    <td><input checked="checked" class="state1" name="[1].Destination" style="width: 50px" type="radio" value="State 1" /></td>
                    <td><input class="state2" name="[1].Destination" style="width: 50px" type="radio" value="State 2" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="field1" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field m_Field1 must be a number." data-val-required="The m_Field1 field is required." name="[1].m_Field1" style="width:200px" type="text" value="0,99" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="[1].m_Field1" data-valmsg-replace="false">Field 1 must be a number.</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="field2" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field m_Field2 must be a number." data-val-required="The m_Field2 field is required." name="[1].m_Field2" style="width:200px" type="text" value="1,00" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="[1].m_Field2" data-valmsg-replace="false">Field2 must be a number.</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="field3" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field m_Field3 must be a number." data-val-required="The m_Field3 field is required." name="[1].m_Field3" style="width:200px" type="text" value="1,00" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="[1].m_Field3" data-valmsg-replace="false">Field 3 must be a number.</span>
                    </td>
                    <td><a href="/Inventory/DisplayItem/2">See other information</a></td>

                    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field OtrObjID must be a number." data-val-required="The OtrObjID field is required." name="[1].OtrObjID" type="hidden" value="2" />
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ObjID must be a number." data-val-required="The ObjID field is required." name="[1].ObjID" type="hidden" value="2" />
                    <input name="[1].m_Field1" type="hidden" value="0,99" />
                    <input name="[1].m_Field2" type="hidden" value="1,00" />
                    <input name="[1].m_Field3" type="hidden" value="1,00" />
                </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="float-right">
            <input type="submit" value="Ready!"/>    
        </div>
    </form>
</p>
```

Comment: Can you post the entire HTML output, not just the snippets?

Comment: Ok, I will do something for this.

Comment: @HerveS Are you using HTML 5?

Comment: MVC asp.net, using view, so I suppose it's HTML5.

Comment: @rae1n I have added the HTML output up there. Tell me if something is wrong or missing.

Comment: Have you checked what you send to the page (before rendering) and what you get back on the POST? Are they equal? Different?

Comment: When in my HttpPost method, the list of items contains the proper items with the good OtrObjID. Then I render my view and that's where the OtrObjID get somehow modified. When I execute the next action (which simply send the list displayed to another method in my controller), the list is ok but each OtrObjID is modified as show up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple html hidden field control

```
<input type="hidden" value="x[i].OtrObjID" name="OtrObjID" />
```

Comment: actually when you use "@Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].OtrObjID)", then the properties of the control rendered automatically.So you cannot manipulate it.

Answer (score 2):

The "problem" is that you have `@model IEnumerable<Model>` that'll force the `[#]` prefix.

<strike>One possible solution would be to wrap your Model inside a ViewModel.</strike>

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Model> Models { get; set; }
}
```

And then use `@model ViewModel`

I'd also like to suggest the use of `@foreach` as it's cleaner.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Models) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.ObjName)
            (...)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.OtrObjID)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

**Note**: I put everything inside the `<td>` as it's not valid HTML to have anything other than `<td>` or `<th>` inside the `<tr>` tag. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tr.asp

Comment: Seriously? Wow, that's interesting! I'll try it along and get you back on this.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty, and I'm not 100% sure my solution will work. But it's on the right path :). If it doesn't work I'll help you figure out another way.

Comment: No problems. I have a LOT of work to do as this view is not the original one, so I need to change about everything to this new ViewModel class you introduced, but things are on their way and should be done early afternoon (12pm here).
Gotta go eat, I'll get you back on this later on ;)

Comment: Well, I've tried what you suggested, but the result is identical. Switching to a simple model that has a list of IEnumerable models gives out the same result.